# Tips for telling googlebot to leave our ajax api urls alone

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt, googlebot

Getting frustrated with the googlebot trying to index our ajax links, all which live at the path `/umbraco/api/*` (and beyond).

Currently robots.txt looks like:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /umbraco/api/* 
Sitemap: http://{site.web}/sitemap/index
```

Updated about a week ago. Trigerred through web master tools. Still there it is filling up our error logs.

It wouldn't be so bad, but those are `application/json` resources, and that is not in the list of gbot's  `HTTP_ACCEPT` list, so that is why we are getting a server exception.

Any other tips for that one?

Comment: Lots on this in [**google serps**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=robots.txt%20googlebot%20exclude%20ajax%20api%20urls) (including 4 potential SO dupes).

Comment: and that hasn't worked...can you be specific about any of those links solving gbot ignoring robots.txt?

Comment: having this same issue 6 years on... anyone found a solution?